# Ruby design strategy on using "retry" logic

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am dealing with an API that requires me to do the following (the API can not be changed):

1. Log into the service to use it (login)
2. Use the api method passing some token info from login and some api method specific parameters (each such method invocation is wrapped in its own "api_user" method - see below).

In step 2 though, the api can result in certain exceptions in which case I have to retry the login method and invoke the same api again with new token. Each of the api methods may have additional parameters (apart from the token parameter). Conceptually, if I have already logged in, I have the token now which can be used for some time.

```
def api_user
  begin
    api_method1 token, x,y,z
  RetryException => e
    new_token = login
    api_method1 token, x,y,z
  end
end
```

How do I do this elegantly?
Option 1:

For each api_user method - do the above individually

Option 2:
Use ruby's metaprogramming. I have tried to show this below.

```
class Y
  def self.api_invoker(token,y,z)
    if token == 'old'
      raise "Old token - renew it"
    end 
    puts "Token = #{token}"
  end 

  def self.call_method(m, *params)
    method = Y.method(m)
    begin
      method.call(*params)
    rescue Exception => e
      if e.message.include? "Old token"
        puts "params before = #{params}"
        params[0] = "new"
        puts "params after = #{params}"
        method.call(*params)
      end 
    end 
  end 

end
```

If you invoke the above method as follows, the retrial is triggered and the "new" token is passed to the second invocation of the method.

```
Y.call_method("api_invoker", "old",2,3)
```

I dont like the design since
1. it seems a bit complicated though I prefer it to the option 1 since it removes the duplicate retry logic from all api invoker methods.
2. Since ruby does not have access to parameters using their names, I have to force the convention of making the token parameter the first parameter in all "api invoker" methods. This is so that I can then replace that parameter with the new token in a retrial attempt.

If ruby had a way to access parameters using their names, the above would have been an acceptable design.

Can you suggest a better way?

Thanks!
PS: I can pass all parameters in a "hash" for each api_invoker and then use the token parameter name to access it regardless of where it is positioned (similar to as mentioned in the link http://deepfall.blogspot.com/2008/08/named-parameters-in-ruby.html - but that seems even uglier to me.

Comment: Why don't you hide that token away in a Connection class that you use to access the API? (Why do the users of your API adapter need that token?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The API is not in my hands as I have mentioned - it is an external api out of my control. And hiding it in a connection class would not help once the token becomes old.

Comment: Well I thought you were encapsulating the external API in an adapter. Once the token gets old, the connection (adapter) would have the responsibility to relogin and get a new one. (You would access the API through your own interface that does that token handling for you.)

Comment: Ah...I see. The problem is that the way I know when the token gets old is after I have used an api method and it throws an exception. So unless I am missing something, the real issue is in how to retry with new tokens for any api calls - my example should clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Went with option 2 to avoid repeating the try catch block.